# Why is the apple pencil (1 and 2) so long?

Tags: apple-pencil

Both apple pencils are around an inch longer than my average actual pens. I love the fact that the apple pencil 2 is considerably lighter, but it still is uncomfortably long and gives an unbalanced writing feeling.

Does anyone know if the length is intentional, or more of a technical restraint at this present time?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking *how/why Apple does something is outside the scope of what can be asked as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much technological reasons.

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+Pencil+Teardown/52955

Comment: And yet the Surface pen, which is objectively better, is as long as a regular pen.